# SQL query failing on joined tables with statement

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php

        $sql_1 = $GLOBALS['dbh']->query('SELECT * from ogrlice WHERE izdvojen = 1');

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($sql_1 as $row) {
            $i++;
            if ($i > 4) {
                break;
            }
            $GLOBALS['logger']->write("MySQL: Fetching..."); ?>

             /* ECHOING STUFFS */

        <?php } 

        $MySQL->close();

        ?>
```

This is my code, and this is my problem.

```
$sql_1 = $GLOBALS['dbh']->query('SELECT * from ogrlice WHERE izdvojen = 1');
```

This query works fine, however this is failing.

```
$sql_1 = $GLOBALS['dbh']->query('SELECT * from ogrlice, brosevi WHERE izdvojen = 1');
```

BUT, this works fine.

```
$sql_1 = $GLOBALS['dbh']->query('SELECT * from ogrlice');
```

And returns the whole unfiltered table.

I use PDO.

Comment: You should add some kind of error handling to see what is actually failing. One way would be to use exceptions (bit harder to miss): `$GLOBALS['dbh']->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`, see [PDO: Errors and error handling](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)

Answer (score 0):

`$sql_1 = $GLOBALS['dbh']->query('SELECT * from ogrlice, brosevi WHERE izdvojen = 1');`

returns a cross product, because you miss the join part:

```
$sql_1 = $GLOBALS['dbh']->query('SELECT * from ogrlice, brosevi WHERE ogrlice.id = brosevi.ogrlice_id  and izdvojen = 1');
```

Comment: foreach is still complaining that the argument given is invalid. a var_dump on $sql_1 gives a bool(false);